# Hover, Hover-out, Cicked

Tags: jquery, click, hover

```
$('#box_1, #box_2, #box_3, #box_4').hover(function() {
$(this).addClass('hover');
}, function() {
$(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

But when I clicked, "`HOVER`" `class = .removeClass('hover')`

Anyway to stay this "`HOVER`" class when I clicked ?

http://jsfiddle.net/EAa6p/ (This is my original)

---

DONE ! by Ben <3
http://jsfiddle.net/EAa6p/1/
Thanks you all

Comment: @I2aelba Consider `#box_1:hover { ... }` etc. instead of `.hover { ... }`

Comment: i must use jQuery, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean to persist the hover class when a click occur.

The best option is to use [data()](http://docs.jquery.com/Data) to save the state and check on the hover out

```
var boxes = $('#box_1, #box_2, #box_3, #box_4');
boxes.hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
}, function() {
    if (!$(this).data('clicked'))
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
}).click(function(){

    boxes.not(this).removeClass('hover').data('clicked',false);;
    $(this).data('clicked',true);

});
```

Is that what you wanted?

http://jsfiddle.net/uhc9S/

Comment: Soon. But when i click another box need to .removeClass('hover');

Comment: cant remember if it's not(this) or not($(this)), try the other if it doesn't work

Comment: i try to click click and click for testing bug. All = class "hover"

Answer (score 0):

Use mouseover and mouseout

```
$('#box_1, #box_2, #box_3, #box_4').mouseover(function(){
   $(this).addClass('hover');
}).mouseout(function(){
   $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

Comment: that doesn't answer the question (i know, the question is oddly phrased)

Comment: $('#box_1, #box_2, #box_3, #box_4').mouseover(function(){
   $(this).addClass('hover');
});

$('#box_1, #box_2, #box_3, #box_4').mouseout(function(){
   $(this).removeClass('hover');
});

$('#box_1, #box_2, #box_3, #box_4').click(function(){
   $(this).addClass('hover');
});

Dosnt work like :hover :active in CSS :(

Answer (score 0):

CSS: Change your `.hover{...}` rule to

```
#box_1:hover, #box_1.hover,
#box_2:hover, #box_2.hover,
#box_3:hover, #box_3.hover,
#box_4:hover, #box_4.hover {
    ...
}
```

JavaScript/jQuery: Don't add the hover class on hover and remove it on unhover. Instead, CSS will handle hover and jQuery just has to handle click:

```
$('#box_1, #box_2, #box_3, #box_4').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
});
```

The `:hover` rule means it is hovered. The `.hover` rule will be used when you want it to look hovered after it is clicked.

Comment: doesn't answer the question either

Comment: @Ben: Doesn't he want it to stay looking hovered when he clicks?

Comment: yes, but your code doesn't change anything. When the hover out function is called (i think he wants to keep that part), the hover will be gone

Comment: @I2aelba: Probably should have provided this first thing. It would have helped.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/hRnQE/

on click, toggle another 'different' class that does the same thing...

js

```
$("#box-1, #box-2, #box-3").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
});

$("#box-1, #box-2, #box-3").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("hover-clicked");
});
```

css

```
.hover {color:red;}
.hover-clicked {color:red;}
```

Comment: interesting alternative approach to the problem

Answer (score 0):

Keep one variable which contains the id of the menuitem clicked

```
var currentSelected = null;

$('#box_1, #box_2, #box_3, #box_4').click(function(){
     currentSelected = this.id;   
});

$('#box_1, #box_2, #box_3, #box_4').hover(function(){
    if (this.id !== currentSelected){
        $(this).addClass("hover");
    }
},
function(){
    if (this.id !== currentSelected){
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
    }
});
```